# Are there facilities to recharge batteries on Oman Air flights to Thailand via Muscat?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, power, oman-air

I recently bought a ticket for a flight from Munich to Bangkok via Muscat with Oman Air. I took a peek at their fleet but it seemed like I wasn't able to get the information I needed.

Is there any possibility to plug in adapters and charge the batteries of my mobile stuff (cell phone, notebook, etc.) in those airplanes?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Oman_Air/information.php . Seems like their A330 have power (one plug shared per two seats in Economy), but not their 737 and Turboprops.

Comment: @drat make that an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [SeatGuru page on Oman Air](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Oman_Air/information.php) (you can click on the plane model to see the details), there are power outlets on some of the planes, notably their A330s, while the other models don't have power outlets.

A330-200:

> There is regular AC power onboard: one power port per First and  Business Class seat and one shared between two seats within Economy.

A330-300:

> There is regular AC power onboard: one power port per First and Business Class seat and one shared between two seats within Economy. All seats also have USB ports.

Answer (score 2):

Both [Oman Air Flight 124 from Munich to Muscat](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/OMA124/history/20150417/1030Z/EDDM/OOMS) and 
[Flight 815 from Muscat to Bangkok](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/OMA815/history/20150304/0610Z/OOMS/VTBS) usually operate with an Airbus A330-200, which has [power plugs in all classes](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Oman_Air/Oman_Air_Airbus_330-200.php) (one per seat in First/Biz, one per two seats in Economy).

Beware that aircraft types are never guaranteed, so you may end up on another plane with no notice.   However, Oman Air's only other long-haul aircraft capable of flying to Bangkok is the [A330-300](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Oman_Air/Oman_Air_Airbus_330-300.php), which also has power plugs.